Singularities when Solving Geodesic Equations on a unit Sphere
I’ve recently started revisiting differential geometry, and I’m currently working through an exercise in my textbook that involves deriving the equation of the minimum geodesic on a unit sphere, which should correspond to an arc of a great circle. It’s been a while since I last used the Euler-Lagrange equation, so please bear with me if my question is basic or if I’ve overlooked something obvious.
I’m attempting to solve the first-order differential equations directly, rather than converting them into second-order differential equations, but I’ve encountered a limitation: a singularity arises in the solution.
Here’s how I’ve set up the problem:
Given the metric:
$$
ds^2 = R^2 \left( d\phi^2 + \sin^2(\phi) d\theta^2 \right)
$$
I use the Lagrangian:
$$
L = \sqrt{\dot{\phi}^2 + \sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}^2}
$$
where $\dot{\phi} = \frac{d\phi}{dt}$ and $\dot{\theta} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$, and $t$ is an arbitrary parameter along the geodesic.
The Euler-Lagrange equations for $\phi$ and $\theta$:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} -\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}} \right) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} - \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} \right) = 0
$$
For $\theta$:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \frac{\sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}}{\sqrt{\dot{\phi}^2 + \sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}^2}}
$$
For $\phi$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}}{\sqrt{\dot{\phi}^2 + \sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}^2}} \right) = 0
$$
This implies the quantity is constant, so integrating directly gives:
$$
C_2 = \sin^2(\phi) \dot{\theta}
$$
And this is exactly where I struggle. Solving for $\dot{\theta}$ would introduce a singularity at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$. Interestingly, this problem doesn’t arise when I approach it using the second-order differential equations.Could someone help me understand what I might be missing? Shouldn’t both approaches yield the same result?

Haven't gone through your calculation in detail, but $\sin\phi=0$ at the poles of the sphere, where "the coordinate system is singular."
